# Vacuum chamber that prohibits EM wave propagation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Is it possible to create a vacuum chamber (something like vacuum tube) in which EM wave propagation is prohibited and EM radiation does not exist at all?

Comment: EM waves propagate through vacuum.

Comment: Yes I know I am wondering if there could be a vacuum place (artificially created probably) in which EM waves are turned off!

Comment: see [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yes that was what I was looking for, but can this cage block EM waves in the whole frequency range because as I can see from the pictures the external light enters inside the cage?

Comment: I also read that EM shielding can reduce the EM field but for certain frequency not for all!

Comment: Probably only for extremely dense material of the wall this could happen for all the wave lengths!

Comment: I was going to write an answer explaining that even with a Faraday cage, you still have radiation inside the tube, but I see an answer was already accepted so I'll leave this as a comment. Even if you block out all external radiation, if the vacuum tube walls are at non-zero temperature, the vacuum tube will be filled with what is called [thermal radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation).

Comment: Such a thing does not exist. It's forbidden by the third law of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As energy of the photon increases, additional shielding is required. So something designed for microwaves doesn't keep light out: this lets you watch your food cooking. Optical shielding doesn't stop x-rays, and continuing up the photo energy scale, there is no end in sight.

Note that a Faraday cage does not limit propagation inside of itself; the microwave oven has a Faraday cage to keep the microwaves inside.